# Remove or Delete feature in vector.layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Now, I had problem on removing entities that is already displayed on openlayers.
I have two sources KML that contains the path of a vehicle.

kml1 10 placemarks
kml2 50 placemarks

I first displays the kml1 that stores in **start.vectorsource** variable the  loading the page
and after using a tool that needs to display the kml2 and stores in the start.vectorfiltered variable.
Comparing the two variables content so if there is an element (**feature**) of start.vectorfiltered in **start.vectorsource**, it removes this item
Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
start.vectorsource.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
            if (typeof feature.getId() !== "undefined") {
                if (feature.getId().indexOf(mobileName) !== -1) {
                    entity.push(feature.getId());
                }
            }

        });
        start.vectorfiltered.getSource().getFeatures().forEach(function (feature) {
            if (typeof feature.getId() !== "undefined") {
                for (var k = 0; k < entity.length; k++) {
                    if (feature.getId() === entity[k]) {
                        console.log(feature.getId() + " " + entity[k]);
                        start.vectorsource.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
                    }
                }
            }
            interfaces.newFeature.push(feature);
        });
```

I analyze a start.vectorsource to retrieve the item ID (feature.getId ()) and I'm looking on the ID if it contains the vehicle name (mobilename).
if it has, I store the ID in the variable entity

I analyze a start.vectorfiltered and I compare with the variable entity, if they are equal, it removes the feature in start.vectorsource by its ID.

Here is the error gets :

```
TypeError: this.s[b] is undefined http://localhost:7299/js/ol3/ol.js Line 636
```

Comment: Use a debug build (ol-debug.js) to report errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you don't have an actual ID so `feature.getId()` won't work.

Try instead `feature.get('id')` this is probably due to the fact that your ID is only an attribute of the feature